# Origin of the story "Death in Tehran"

Tags: viktor-frankl, mans-search-for-meaning

During my second read of "Mans's Search For Meaning" by Viktor E. Frankl I noticed that the way he introduces this story "Does this not bring to mind the story of Death in Tehran" implies, that he did not invent this story himself and that he considers it "common knowledge".

**Where is this story from/any other literature for further reading?**

Story:

> A rich and mighty Persian once walked in his garden with one of his servants. The servant cried that he had just encountered Death, who had threatened him. He begged his master to give him his fastest horse so that he could make haste and flee to Teheran, which he could reach that same evening. The master consented and the servant galloped off on the horse. On returning to his house the master himself met Death, and questioned him, “Why did you terrify and threaten my servant?” “I did not threaten him; I only showed surprise in still finding him here when I planned to meet him tonight in Teheran,” said Death.

Comment: [This discussion](https://www.reddit.com/r/psychoanalysis/comments/z3d0pg/stories_and_fables_like_death_in_tehran/) claims that it's similar to one of Aesop's Fables.  IIRC a similar tale in a Middle Eastern setting is referenced in Agatha Christie's _Appointment with Death_.

Comment: Is the italicized part a quote? If so, you could make it more readable by using **quote formatting**, which on this site means starting the line with a greater-than sign. e.g. `> quote here`

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The version of the story I am familiar with, ["An Appointment in Samarra"](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Appointment_in_Samarra), has a different venue but in other respects it is almost identical. This is a retelling of an ancient Mesopotamian legend by W. Somerset Maugham in 1933, which appeared in his play "[Sheppey](https://archive.org/details/in.ernet.dli.2015.125970/page/n645/mode/2up?q=samarra)". The story runs as:

> There was a merchant in Bagdad who sent his servant to market to buy
> provisions and in a little while the servant came back, white and
> trembling, and said, Master, just now when I was in the marketplace I
> was jostled by a woman in the crowd and when I turned I saw it was
> Death that jostled me.  She looked at me and made a threatening
> gesture,  now, lend me your horse, and I will ride away from this city
> and avoid my fate.  I will go to Samarra and there Death will not find
> me.  The merchant lent him his horse, and the servant mounted it, and
> he dug his spurs in its flanks and as fast as the horse could gallop
> he went.  Then the merchant went down to the marketplace and he saw me
> standing in the crowd and he came to me and said, Why did you make a
> threating getsture to my servant when you saw him this morning?  That
> was not a threatening gesture, I said, it was only a start of
> surprise.  I was astonished to see him in Bagdad, for I had an
> appointment with him tonight in Samarra.

As wikipedia notes, Maugham's retelling originates from the Babylonian talmud, [Sukkah 53a](https://www.sefaria.org/Sukkah.53a.6?lang=bi), which changes the venue again, this time to Luz:

> There were once two Cushites who attended on Solomon, and these were
> Elihoreph and Ahyah, the sons of Shisha, scribes, of Solomon. One day
> Solomon observed that the Angel of Death was sad. ‘Why’, he said to
> him, ‘art thou sad?’ — ‘Because’, he answered him, ‘they have demanded
> from me the two Cushites who sit here’. [Solomon thereupon] gave them
> in charge of the spirits and sent them to the district of Luz. When,
> however, they reached the district of Luz they died. On the following
> day, he observed that the Angel of Death was in cheerful spirits.
> ‘Why’, he said to him, ‘art thou cheerful?’ — ‘To the place’, the
> other replied, ‘where they expected them from me, thither didst thou
> send them!’ Solomon thereupon uttered the saying, ‘A man's feet are
> responsible for him; they lead him to the place where he is wanted’.

The same story is also present in Islamic literature, with the venue shifted again, this time to India:

> Abū ‘l-Shaykh from Dā’ūd ibn Abī Hind; he said: It reached me that the
> Angel of Death was made responsible for Solomon (peace be upon him),
> and he was told: ‘Go into his presence every day, and ask what he
> needs; then do not leave him until you have performed it.’ He used to
> enter upon him in the image of a man, and he would ask him how he was.
> Then he would say: ‘Messenger of God, do you need anything?’ If he
> said: ‘Yes’, then he did not leave him until he had done it; and if he
> said: ‘No’, then he left him until the following morning. One day he
> entered upon him while there was an old man with him. [Solomon] stood
> up, and greeted [him], then [the Angel of Death] said: ‘Do you need
> anything, Messenger of God?’ He said: ‘No.’ The [angel] glanced at
> [the old man] and the old man trembled; the Angel of Death left and
> the old man stood up and said to Solomon: ‘I beg you, by the truth of
> God! to command the wind to carry me and throw me down on the furthest
> lump of mud in the land of India (hind)!’ So [Solomon] commanded it
> and it carried him [there].
>
> The Angel of Death came unto Solomon the next morning and asked him
> about the old man. [The Angel of Death] said: ‘His book came down to
> me yesterday, [saying] that I should take his soul tomorrow at the
> rising of dawn in the furthest lump of mud in the land of India; but
> when I came down, and thinking that he was there, I then found him
> with you. I was astonished and could not think of [anything] other
> than him; I came down to him today at the break of dawn and found him
> on the highest lump of mud in the land of India, and he trembled, and
> I took his soul (rūh).’

[from *[Angels in Islam](https://books.google.co.in/books?id=IDZACwAAQBAJ)*, a translation of Jalal al-Din al-Suyuti's al-Haba'ik fi akhbar al-mala'ik)]

Comment: Thank you very much <3